# How to swap values in strings without loop

Tags: python, replace

```
string = input('Please enter a string: ')
replaced_string = string.replace(string[0],'e')
replaced_string[0] = string[0]
print(replaced_string)
```

I tried to replace all the letters of the first char in the string but keep the first char as it was, but apparently my code doesn't work on the third line. Can you suggest a solution how to replace it?

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to do?

Comment: Strings are immutable, you need to create a new string with the required values. Look at e.g. the `.replace` method, or `re`gex if you need more control.

Comment: like for example, i want to input dear dorothy and it will print me dear eorothy for a swap of the first char and e

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
input_str = input()    
first_letter = input_str[0]
rest_of_letters = input_str[1:]
# Take the first letter, and append it the rest of the letters, but
# with "e" replaced by the first letter.
replaced_string = first_letter + rest_of_letters.replace(first_letter, 'e')
```

The key problem with how you tried to do it is strings are immutable. You can't do `my_str[0] = "a"`. If you want to modify a string you must create a new string with the modifications you want.

Comment: @maxgof I ran the code above with the input `dear dorothy` and `replaced_string`  contained `dear eorothy` as expected.

Comment: @maxgof then you are doing something else wrong, because `replaced_string` will have exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: @maxgof I tried to make it a bit clearer. Which part do you not understand? `input_str[1:]` will evaluate to `ear dorothy`. We then do a `str.replace()` on that string, to replace 'd' with 'e'.

Comment: just so it will be totally clear the 'input_str[1:]'  is so it start with "ear dortohy" right?

Comment: @maxgof In the code above, `rest_of_letters` is `ear dorothy'. In the last line where we do `rest_of_letters.replace()` this expression returns a *copy* of the string in `rest_of_letters` where the letter `d` is replaced by `e`. If this answer solved your problem, you would help me a lot if you clicked the green tick on the left.

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting what you want to do. but Strings do not support item assignment.